# What is this small insect called?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

It is about 1-2 mm long. It also can fly and it stays on the wall.

Location: Lebanon.

[image]

Comment: Your country/state will help in getting an answer; a more-in-focus photo (if available) would also assist ... the best anyone can do at the moment is "it's a beetle."

Comment: It is in Lebanon. That's the maximum zoom my cell have. Sorry. I want to identify them so I can get rid of them.

Comment: If you are taking pictures with your cellphone it's usually better not to use the zoom. Cell phones, at least the ones I am aware of, don't usually have a real optical zoom, just a digital zoom. Essentially its the same thing as cropping the center out of a picture and then stretching it bigger. You don't actually get any more information.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like a cigarette beetle- they can infest many different types of products so I would definitely check everything carefully. Here's the link I used as a source, you can find more info here: https://www.orkin.com/other/beetles/cigarette-beetles/

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Although this answer might prove to be helpful, you still need to add more details and some images for comparison.